# How to redirect HttpContext to proxy

Tags: c#, javascript, redirect, httphandler, ashx

I am making call to twitter API 1.1 from javascript which need to go via proxy as every other call from this project. Redirect to the proxy is currently served by server side Generic Web handler (ashx):

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

Any call from js goes first to the handler and handler passes this request to the proxy together with proxy credentials. Up until now this was used only for simple calls ignoring headers so creating new WebRequest out of the HttpContext uri was easy way out.

```
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));
    req.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy);  
    req.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(credentials);
```

With OAuth I need the headers so I am trying to find simple way how to redirect the incoming request in form of HttpRequest to the proxy and append only the proxy credential without shifting the headers manually to the new WebRequest. I tried quite few approaches such as `context.Server.TransferRequest(uri,true);` however I didn't find a way how to add the proxy credentials. Moving the headers over to the new request is also not enjoyable task.

Where am I going wrong, this task sounds too simple, but I can't find decent solution ?

Comment: I do not believe you can redirect the incoming HTTP Request. You can easily copy the heads from the incoming request into the out going request to accomplish what you are trying to do.